# Authentication using JWT (JSON Web Token) in Laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to implement authentication in Laravel using tymondesigns/jwt-auth
(JSON Web Token).

Here is some code from my auth.php configuration file:

```
...

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
...
```

Here is one route from my login routes/api.php file:

```
Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
```

Here is my AuthController.php file:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function login() {
        // $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        $credentials = ["email" => "test@test.te", "password" => "test123"];

        if (! ($token = auth()->attempt($credentials))) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type'   => 'bearer',
            'expires_in'   => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is my model class User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'user';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    ...

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        if ( !empty($password) ) {
            $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
        }
    }

}
```

`auth()->attempt($credentials)` in the AuthController@login method returns false but I'm sure that credentials are correctly in the database. I tried to clear caches but still no luck and I cannot get authentication to work. Any reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Some people seem to have trouble using `auth()`. Does it work if you use `Auth::guard()` or `Auth::guard('api')` instead?

Comment: @Dan I tried all of that but I still get the same results.

Comment: Does the login work with the default web guard?

Comment: So I changed the default guard to be "web", I cleared config cache but still doesn't work.

Comment: Then it's not the JWT packages' fault and something else is wrong. Open Tinker with `php artisan tinker` and hash the password again with `bcrypt('test123')`, then save the hash to the database and try logging in again.

Comment: Another guess: is the login route protected with a middleware?

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now! So the problem was hashing. Can you please help me how to save passwords to database? In my seeds file (where I create this test user), I do something like this: `$user->password = Hash::make("test123");` But I guess it's not the right way to hash a password?

Comment: No, that's totally fine. You're hashing the value twice. The first time in the seeder with `Hash::make('test123')` and then the model itself hashes the hashed password a second time because of the `setPasswordAttribute` [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

Comment: Oh now I understand and it's working! Thank you!